# Derby and WSL2: '.': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'webappsDB' mount path must be absolute

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, wsl-2

I'm trying to create a simple volume in WSL2 (Ubuntu) for my local DB created in Derby. I have tried these two pieces of code (and similars) and none of them is working:

**Option 1:**

**Dockerfile:**

```
RUN mkdir -p webappsDB/MY_LOCAL_DB

VOLUME /mnt/c/Users/MY_USER/MY_APP/webappsDB/MY_LOCAL_DB:/usr/local/tomcat/webappsDB/MY_LOCAL_DB
```

**Option 2:**

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: fanmixco/MY_APP:v1.0.0
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/MY_USER/MY_APP/webappsDB/MY_LOCAL_DB:/usr/local/tomcat/webappsDB/MY_LOCAL_DB
```

I'm constantly getting this error:

> ERROR: for app  Cannot create container for service app: invalid
> volume specification: '...:webappsDB:rw': invalid mount config for
> type "volume": invalid mount  path: 'webappsDB' mount path must be
> absolute

I also tried to add:

```
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

And didn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable path conversion from Windows-style to Unix-style in volume definitions

create a new Windows environment variable with the name `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` and set it to `1`

or

create a .env file in the `docker-compose.yml` file path and add the following

`COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

Comment: I added this:
  app:
    image: fanmixco/MY_APP:v1.0.0
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

And still, I have the same error.

Comment: Please do check this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5842#issuecomment-403007997

Comment: This is not for Windows Subsystem Linux 2. I'm not running it under Hyper-V.